# Converting an ISO-8859-1 string to a GSM string in C

Tags: c, sockets, iso-8859-1

I read some text (known to be in ISO-8859-1) from a TCP socket using the read function, then I do some basic substring replacing. Finally I would like to convert the string into the GSM equivalent.

Preferably (but not necessarily) I would do something like this:

```
size_t i;
for (i=0; i<size; i++) {
  switch (string[i]) {
    case 65:
      //Convert this character
    case 163:
      //Convert this character (the pound symbol £)
  }
}
```

I prefer the switch for readability, but have considered if-else statements as well.

This works for the normal ASCII characters, but the top part of the ISO-8859-1 is causing me all kind of problems. Apparently they are considered as multiple characters. Any help on how to proceed with the conversion will be much appreciated.

Comment: If characters from the top half of ISO-8859-1 are appearing as multiple entries in `string`, it is extremely likely that you do *not*, in fact, have an ISO-8859-1-encoded string.  Also, investigate the [`iconv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv) library function.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, that the reason I get problems are due to the top half of ISO-8859-1 getting represented as multiple entries...
But when trying to make a case 163 (the pound symbol £) the compiler start complaining: case label value exceeds maximum value for type

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: What code does the compiler complain about?

Comment: I've actually tried something similar to the code snippet from the OP. As mentioned the compiler complains when I get to case's above 127.

I tried to find some solution on several forums (stack overflow being one of them), but to little avail.

Zack mentioned the iconv library as a possibility, but as I recall the GSM encoding are not part of it (please correct me if I'm wrong).

If anyone can point me in the right direction (with a link or otherwise) it would be much appreciated. I do not expect a full-fledged solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `char` seems to be signed. You could use char literals and circumvent the whole issue with the sign of char values beyond ASCII 127:

```
/* ascii: */
case '\000': /* U+0000 - nul */
...    
/* extended ascii: */
case '\200': /* U+0080 - non-printable control character */
...
case '\243': /* U+00A3 - sterling pound */
...
case '\377': /* U+00ff - lower case y with dieresis */
```

The conversion is probably more efficiently to implement by a look-up in an array, though.

If the "extended ASCII" part of your input is represented as multiple characters, it's likely that your input is actually encoded in UTF-8 or something similar.

Comment: This actually seems to help me out. Thank you very much :o)
When you say it would be more efficient to implement the conversion as a look-up in an array, what do you mean?

Comment: Define the mapping in an array like `char map[]` and use the ordinal value of input character as an index into the array, so that `map['A']` returns the code for A (0x41 in GSM?). To deal with negative char values you can do a bitwise and with 0xFF for the lookup: `map[c & 0xff]`

Comment: @Joni: It probably would need to be a `std::string map[256]` since GSM uses a multi-septet (!) encoding.

Comment: I tend to recommend aggressive use of `unsigned char` whenever there's any possibility of characters outside US-ASCII (whatever their encoding) but you do wind up writing lots of wrappers for `string.h` functions if you do that.